# interfering with mongo.exe with console

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
psi.Arguments = @"/C cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin & dir & pause";
using (Process p = Process.Start(psi))
{
p.WaitForExit();
}
```

With this code, I first open cmd and then run mongo.exe. But after switching to mongo shell, I can't send any commands (with Code). 
My goal is to automate Mongo ReplicaSet. For this, I need to get input and output by interfering with mongoshell.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why are you not running MongoDB as a service?

Comment: What do you mean by "automate Mongo ReplicaSet"?

Comment: I am manually replicating the Mongo db. I am trying to do this automatically. This is a small part of my problem. The important thing is to enter commands in mongoshell. @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: it's not clear what exactly you're trying to do here, but [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#eval-option) may help.

Comment: it's pretty simple actually. First, I open the CMD in the program. Then I open the mongoshell. However, I cannot enter commands in mongoshell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easier way of doing this.

1. Start the MongoDB instance and put it in background.
2. Open a new mongo shell and run your commands.

   - When you like to use the mongo shell then you should use native JavaScript commands, i.e. start shell with javascript file name (see [Core Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-shell-file))
   - If you prefer to do all in C# then you should use the [MongoDB C#/.NET Driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/)
3. As last command in your shell script put `db.getSiblingDB("admin").shutdownServer()` - by this the first window will terminate and you don't need any `WaitForExit()`